# touchpad + QToolButton = supperios press

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt4, x11

I have `QToolButton`:

```
btn_ = new QToolButton(this);
btn_->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
btn_->setAutoRepeat(false);
connect(btn_, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(btnPressed()));
```

and my slot called twice per on `appreciable` press on touchpad.

During debug of my program I can see that the first one call from `QAbstractButton::mousePressEvent`
and the second one `QAbstractButton::mouseMoveEvent`.

If I press touchpad with one instantaneous and then remove hand from
touchpad, then I got only one call of `btnPressed` from `QAbstractButton::mousePressEvent`.

Any idea how to fix this issue? So I have not remove hands from notebook's touchpad
for pressing. I think about timer to measure time from one `btnPressed` to another,
but have no idea of value of timeout to prevent this. I can of course choose timeout for my notebook, but what if on another notebook it will be too small,
or if choose big one, then users start complains about not responsible  interface.

linux/x11/qt4.8/amd64

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`clicked()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) instead of `pressed()`, as it reflects the behaviour the user expect from a single button press/click. In general, if you're not sure you really want the slot called instantly at pressing the button (and handle the special cases that may come with that), you should use `clicked()`.